# ARM deployment of Azure Search Service - Generate Query Key

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I am trying to generate the Azure Search Service and along with it to have a query key. How to do it and how to retrieve it later in arm template?

So far, my search script:

```
{
  "apiVersion": "2015-08-19",
  "name": "[variables('azureSearchName')]",
  "location": "australiaeast",
  "sku": {
    "name": "basic"
  },
  "type": "Microsoft.Search/searchServices",
  "properties": {
    "replicaCount": 1,
    "partitionCount": 1,
    "hostingMode": "Default"
  }
}
```

And to grab its admin key:

```
"searchKey": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "[listAdminKeys(resourceId('ResourceGroup', 'Microsoft.Search/searchServices', 'SearchName'), '2015-08-19').PrimaryKey]"
}
```

**UPDATE**

After the answer from @4c74356b41 I continued some digging and found this operation on [Microsoft.Search - /searchServices/listQueryKeys/read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations#microsoftsearch). Unfortunately, it is "read" and not "action", so when I try to use it like this:

```
 "searchKey": {
    "type": "object",
    "value": "[listQueryKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Search/searchServices', 'SearchName'), '2015-08-19')]"
 }
```

I am getting

> Deployment failed. Correlation ID:
>   486ae99b-839d-43bf-93e7-f0e2afc3f19a. {   "Message": "The requested
>   resource does not support http method 'POST'." }

How to call it using GET?

Answer (score 0):

it would probably look like something like this:

```
{
  "apiVersion": "2015-08-19",
  "name": "[concat(variables('azureSearchName'), '/keyNamegoesHere')]",
  "location": "australiaeast",
  "type": "Microsoft.Search/searchServices/createQueryKey"
}
```

but I wouldnt be surprised if that doesnt work. Reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchmanagement/querykeys/create

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I have at least a direction to look! Suggested snippet is not working with a dumd "Bad Request" error message, so I am still trying something. Also updated my question in regards to reading. Do you have any other suggestions, maybe?

Comment: @JleruOHeP Have you solved this by any chance? If you did and you would share what you did it would help me a lot.